# Change size of inputs in Bootstrap form-inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to narrow size of input in bootstrap 3 because it's too big for my nav-bar.

I tried with

```
<label class="col-sm-2 sr-only" for=”email">Email   address</label>
```

but it didn't work. Neither with

```
<div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
```

Neither with

```
<input  type="email" width="60px" class="form-control" id=”email"   placeholder="Email">

<form class="form-inline">  
    <div class="form-group">    
        <label class="sr-only" for=”email">Email address</label>    
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id=”email" placeholder="Email">    
    </div>  
    <div class="form-group">        
        <label class="sr-only" for=”password">Password</label>      
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id=”password"   placeholder="Password"> 
    </div>  
    <div class="checkbox">  
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox">Remember me</label>  
    </div>  
    <buRon type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</buRon>    
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can set an alternate class for your narrow inputs and by using `max-width` property, you can keep it as responsive element.

```
input.my-narrow-input {max-width:200px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the provided HTML code I would say use the 'Control Sizing' provided by Bootstrap:
[Bootstrap: Control Sizes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes)

You said it is to big for an input form inside nav-bar did u add the class

```
navbar-form
```

Which used in the bootstrap provided example gives:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

All inputs under the `form-inline` have width set to auto. Add your own styles if you want them narrower:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .form-inline .form-control {
        width: 100px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `input` inside one more wrapper, for example:

```
<form class="form-inline">  
  <div class="form-group">    
    <label class="sr-only" for=”email">Email address</label>    
    <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="email" class="form-control" id=”email" placeholder="Email"></div>    
</div>  
<div class="form-group">        
    <label class="sr-only" for=”password">Password</label>      
    <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="password" class="form-control" id=”password"   placeholder="Password"></div> 
</div>  
<div class="checkbox">  
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox">Remember me</label>  
</div>  
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
```

Comment: @JoaquínFdez, did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Best solution for my navbar has been a mix of Kamuran and Kieken72:

```
<form   class="navbar-form navbar-right">
<div    class="form-group">
<label  class="sr-only" for=”email">Email   address</label>
<input type="email" class="form-control my-narrow-input"    id=”email"    placeholder="Email">
</div>
<div    class="form-group">
<label  class="sr-only" for=”password">Password</label>
<input  type="password" class="form-control my-narrow-input"     id=”password"  placeholder="Password">
</div>
<div    class="checkbox">
<label> <input  type="checkbox">    <span style="color:white">Remember   me</span></label>
</div>
<buRon  type="submit"   class="btn  btn-sm btn-info">Sign   in</buRon>
</form>
```